# Email Questions which meet condition XYZ

Tags: feature-request, support, feed, email-notification

I would like to get email messages once a day (for example at 8 o'clock in the morning) about questions on a specific site (Stack Overflow) which are tagged with my most recent used tags which have no accepted answer yet but are older than one day. Is this possible?

I do not wan't to enter the tags myself but rather use the data from "Personalized predictions" which can be found under `Site Settings -> Preferences -> Personalized predictions`.

By "most recent used tags" I mean tags for which I wrote questions and tags from questions I recently viewed a lot.

If something like the above is possible with an RSS Reader (without the time requirement) I would be also happy.